# ocaml parse string "*" into * ocaml operator?

Tags: string, ocaml

I have a function

```
 val do_math s : string -> int
```

called like:

```
 do_math "3*4"
```

that will return the int 12

given the string input is there a way to parse the * out with sub or something so that I can give do_math other strings like "3-1" and it will return int 2?

I'm trying to avoid having to write all that extra code...

I came up with something like this after reading your answer but it says something about this not being function and not being able to be applied. And the fact that the variable op_match is not used , however I do not know how to get the value from that variable as a return value.

```
open String
let do_math s =
  let num1 = int_of_string (sub s 0 1) in
  let num2 = int_of_string (sub s (length s - 1)1) in
  let op = (sub s 1 2) in
  match op with
  | "+" -> num1 + num2
  | "-" -> num1 - num2
  | "*" -> num1 * num2
  | "/" -> num1 / num2
  | _ -> num1 + num2
```

Comment: Change `sub` to `String.sub` and `length` to `String.length`. Change second call to `String.sub` to extract the last character: `String.sub s (String.length s - 1) 1` Remove `let op_match =`. Then it works for me. But it's exceptionally inflexible of course.

Comment: I forgot to include my open statement. but i changed the other parts.

Comment: It works now - I'll probably add more cases or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to look at this is that OCaml is a compiled language, so it doesn't come with runtime facilities for parsing and evaluating expressions. In interpreted languages these are often available "for free" because the interpreter is already doing these operations anyway.

Your best bet is to find an expression evaluation library that you can link to. If you're not worried about efficiency, you could run a command to do your calculations. In fact you could even run the OCaml interpreter :-)

One such library that I've seen in use is [GNU matheval](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmatheval/).

Comment: running the ocaml interpreter sounds like a horrible hack lol.

Answer (score 3):

You can write you own parser for calculator like expression language using [Genlex](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Genlex.html) module. It even comes with example of writing a calculator. The `Genlex` module is also covered in [OCaml O'Reilly Book](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/index.html). The [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/coreexamples.html#sec14) itself, can help you in writing actual interpreter. 
Also, I once wrote a parser and [interpreter](https://github.com/ivg/expr) of a little bit enriched expression language, so you can consult or use it, if you find it useful.

Comment: It's true, code for evaluating expressions is an extremely common example when first learning a language. I'm sure there are many of them in OCaml. There's an evaluator (not a parser) in [Chapter 1.7](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/coreexamples.html#sec14) of the OCaml manual in fact.

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: @JeffreyScofield, thanks, I've updated the posting with a link. For the sake of future generations))

Comment: you mean stream syntax? I doubt so. But there is no need in general to use it, as `Genlex` is useful by itself as a library. Especially for small calculator mini-dsls. For anything else, it is better to use menhir.